# Query trying to select but get ambiguous error?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

It runs but I select all the columns. Can someone explain to me why my first query doesn't work? I don't think I need a join. If I can get some help that would be good. To be quite honest I've never seen the error before. If it works with SELECT*, I don't understand why I have issues with select specific columns.

These are my tables:

```
create table product
(
pdt# varchar(10) not null,
pdt_name varchar(30) not null,
pdt_label varchar(30) not null,
constraint product_pk primary key (pdt#));

create table orders
(
pdt# varchar(10) not null,
qty number(11,0) not null,
city varchar(30) not null
);
```

And these are the values

```
insert into product values ([111,chair,chr]);
insert into product values ([222,stool,stl]);
insert into product values ([333,table,tbl]);

insert into orders values ([111,22,Ottawa]); 
insert into orders values ([222,22,Ottawa]);  
insert into orders values ([333,22,Toronto]);
```

Question is this:

- c.    List all [pdt#,pdt_name,qty] when the order is from [Ottawa]

I tried:

```
SELECT pdt#, pdt_name, qty FROM orders, product WHERE city='Ottawa';
```

I get column is ambiguously defined error. But when I run:

```
SELECT *, qty FROM orders, product WHERE city='Ottawa';
```

It runs but I select all the columns. Can someone explain to me why my first query doesn't work? I don't think I need a join. If I can get some help that would be good. To be quite honest I've never seen the error before. If it works with SELECT*, I don't understand why I have issues with select specific columns.

Comment: The correct result is from @vkp however in relation to why query 1 doesn't work it's because pdt# exists in both the orders and product tables. You can fix this by specifying which table you want the result from e.g. orders.pdt#, pdt_name.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both the tables have `pdt#` in common and you are `select`ing it in your query. In cases like these, you have to explicitly specify the table from which the column should be picked up.

You should also `join` the tables. Else you would get a `cross-join`ed result.

```
SELECT p.pdt#, p.pdt_name, o.qty 
FROM orders o join product p on o.pdt# = p.pdt#
WHERE o.city='Ottawa';
```

Your second query works because you are selecting all the columns from both the tables and ideally it should not be done. Always specify the columns you need when you are selecting from more than one table.